# Python - Adding rows based on information in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I'm looking to do is to add to the 'TestDate' column based on the information in 'eperf2', 'mperf2', and 'sperf2' columns. The 'StudentTestID' is the unique identifier. In the dataframe if there is anything in the 'eperf2' column for that specific 'StudentTestID' then I want the 'TestDate' to say "April 1". If there is anything in the 'mperf2' column for that same 'StudentTestID' I want to add a row to the dataframe with same number (unique identifier) in 'StudentTestID' column and in the 'TestDate' column I want it to say "May 1". Same thing regarding 'sperf2' column, in that case I want 'TestDate' to say "June 1".

So for each 'StudentTestID' there could be up to 3 different rows with different 'TestDate' info. If 'eperf2', 'mperf2', or 'sperf2' then no need to add a row or have a 'TestDate' for that 'StudentTestID'.

Here is what I have (Disclaimer: I have no idea how to do what I described above):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['sample-mcas.csv']))
df.rename(columns = {'district':'NCESID','sasid':'StudentTestID','stugrade':'StudentGradeLevel'}, inplace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['NCESID','StudentLocalID','StudentTestID','StudentGradeLevel','TestDate','TestName','TestTypeName','TestSubjectName','TestGradeLevel','ScoreLabel','ScoreType', 'ScoreValue','eperf2','mperf2','sperf2'])
df['NCESID'] = 373737
df['StudentLocalID'] = 'missing'

df['TestName'] = 'MCAS'
df['TestGradeLevel'] = df['StudentGradeLevel']
print (df)
```

Here is the output of the above code:

```
    NCESID StudentLocalID  StudentTestID StudentGradeLevel  TestDate  \
0     373737        missing        1408905                 3       NaN   
1     373737        missing        1020285                 3       NaN   
2     373737        missing        1681155                 3       NaN   
3     373737        missing        1987801                 3       NaN   
4     373737        missing        1351732                 3       NaN   
...      ...            ...            ...               ...       ...   
2666  373737        missing        1769669                10       NaN   
2667  373737        missing        1757999                 8       NaN   
2668  373737        missing        1633264                10       NaN   
2669  373737        missing        1760810                 7       NaN   
2670  373737        missing        1108784                 9       NaN   

     TestName  TestTypeName  TestSubjectName TestGradeLevel  ScoreLabel  \
0        MCAS           NaN              NaN              3         NaN   
1        MCAS           NaN              NaN              3         NaN   
2        MCAS           NaN              NaN              3         NaN   
3        MCAS           NaN              NaN              3         NaN   
4        MCAS           NaN              NaN              3         NaN   
...       ...           ...              ...            ...         ...   
2666     MCAS           NaN              NaN             10         NaN   
2667     MCAS           NaN              NaN              8         NaN   
2668     MCAS           NaN              NaN             10         NaN   
2669     MCAS           NaN              NaN              7         NaN   
2670     MCAS           NaN              NaN              9         NaN   

      ScoreType  ScoreValue eperf2 mperf2 sperf2  
0           NaN         NaN      W      W         
1           NaN         NaN     NI      P         
2           NaN         NaN     NI     NI         
3           NaN         NaN      P      P         
4           NaN         NaN      P     NI         
...         ...         ...    ...    ...    ...  
2666        NaN         NaN      F      F      F  
2667        NaN         NaN      P      W      W  
2668        NaN         NaN     NI     NI     NI  
2669        NaN         NaN      W      W         
2670        NaN         NaN
```

[2671 rows x 15 columns]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gives you an idea :)

```
for i in range(3000): # because you have less than 3000 records or use `while loop`
    eperf2 = df.iloc[i][12] # because eperf2 is 12th column
    mperf2 = df.iloc[i][13]
    sperf2 = df.iloc[i][14]
    
    if (eperf2 | mperf2 | sperf2): # of course, create 3 `if` conditions for each date: i.e April 1, etc.
        df.loc[[i],[TestDate]] = `date here`
```

Comment: Thank you, definitely very helpful! So I've been experimenting with it and it game me this error:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
I'm assuming that is because I've only selected certain columns from the original dataframe?

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delayed feedback. I looked up the warning message on this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy. Long story short, `df.loc[[index], [column]]` works without warning. I have edited my answer to reflect this. Would be here if you experience any other issue.